# Is there a proper term for an ex-friend?

Tags: false-friends

Like a term for someone you had a falling out with and no longer associate with? I'm looking for something that doesn't still have the term 'friend' in it.

Comment: My associate.  My acquaintance.  My neighbor.  My co-worker.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that is a [former](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/former) friend. [edit, courtesy Papa Poule] or a former pal/chum/compadre

> former
> adjective
>
> 1 Having previously been a particular thing:
> *her former boyfriend*
>
> 1.1 Of or occurring in the past:
> *the seafarers of former times*
>
> 2 (the former) Denoting the first or first mentioned of two people or things:
> *I take the former view*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/former

Comment: Looking for something that doesn't still have the term 'friend' in it.

Comment: Clear. But foe is such a strong term... Someone actually never a real friend?

Comment: You'd think there'd be some term between friend and enemy :(

Comment: Mmmm backstabber?

Comment: Lol... "This picture here was taken by my backstabber" "My backstabber and I use to sneak into the graveyard at night" "I went there once with my backstabber"

Comment: Oh you are really angry....AND living dangerously... Obviously another term is needed.

Comment: Perhaps just....ex?

Comment: +1 @Casey Bookeater's "former" + [a synonym of "friend"] (pal, chum, compadre) is the only way I see to avoid using "friend," unless you're willing to 'coin'/stretch a new, "former-friend-specific", meaning out of the noun "[has-been](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/has-been), which could possibly be understood in the right context with perhaps less chance of being misunderstood to mean "ex-boy/girl friend" than just "ex" might be.  ("This picture here was taken by [one of] my **has-been** [s]"

Comment: @Papa Poule Good one, adding it to incorporate the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

**frenemy**

**friend-no-more**

**friend-at-the-time**

**enemy-to-become**

**He who shall remain nameless**

**Hugo the Treacherous** (or whatever the person's name is)

This might make for a colorful recounting:

*This picture here was taken by Hugo the Treacherous.*

I had a housemate who referred to her ex as ***Shithead***.  She refused to refer to him by name.

*I went there once with Shithead.*